# Why does a radio station play through my speakers when the laptop runs on battery?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, battery

Every fortnight, on a schedule, I disconnect the charger from my laptop (which is largely stationary anyway) and let the battery run down.

As soon as I disconnected the battery earlier today, I noticed that I could hear a radio station playing through my speakers at a low volume (say, about `1`).  Obviously, I was surprised, because I can positively guarantee that I don't have any music or radio programmes playing in the background (or foreground).  When I plug in the power supply, the low volume playback goes away, but as soon as the laptop begins to run on battery, the radio station becomes audible.

I cannot find any suspicious programmes.  The virus checker has completed its scan and not reported anything.  What could be causing this strange phenomenon?  And should I be worried?

---

P.S. Not that it makes a difference, but the scheduler is actually set on a monthly schedule.  I just felt like using the word "fortnight."  The rest of the posting is true.

Comment: Does it happen outside of Windows (e.g. If you go into the BIOS / UEFI menu)? I guess you could start by determining if it's a hardware / interference issue, or software...

Comment: It is not unheard-of (no pun intended) for high-gain audio circuits to pick up strong local radio stations. (Heck, with sensitive-enough headphones and a long enough antenna you don't even need an amplifier.) In your case I'd guess that the signal is being picked up by the laptop's frame; Plugging it in shunts the signal to ground. Although the question this is supposedly a duplicate of is about headphones, not speakers, the situation is at least similar and you should review the web sites linked there.